# Spurious characters in HTML files using Microsoft Expression

Tags: html, unicode, expression-web

I've got MS Expression Web (12.0.6211.1000).

I usually use Homesite but it and Vista don't get on so I thought I'd try Expression for editing simple HTML files.

I find that Espression Web inserts the characters

```
ï»¿
```

at the top of every file I edit, just before the `<!DOCTYPE...` tag.  What are these and how can I make it stop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Unicode Byte Order Mark interpreted as something that isn't a Unicode character encoding (such as ISO-8859-1 AKA Latin-1).

The W3C has a [guide to specifying which character encoding you are actually using](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset).

If you don't want to use a Unicode encoding (I suggest you do, they are current standard rather than the ISO-8859 series which are legacy) then the [forums](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/web/thread/87a9f332-65e7-4d83-8f6d-46c0d9749ea5/) suggest that you can change the encoding by going to (oddly) File > Properties... > Language and looking for a "Save the document as" list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Unicode Byte Order Mark; Expression Web is saving in UTF-8.